# How to get the string postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to extract `f_sel_policy_ty_static` string from the below large string using postgreSQL(query)?

```
((("current_user"())::text <> ANY (string_to_array('xxxxxxx,yyyyyyy'::text, ','::text))) AND ((sss_key)::text = ANY (string_to_array((sss_sec_typ.f_sel_policy_ty_static())::text, ','::text))))
```

with string as
(
select '(("current_user"())::text <> ANY (string_to_array(''xxxxxxx,yyyyyyy''::text, '',''::text))) AND ((sss_key)::text = ANY (string_to_array((sss_sec_typ.f_sel_policy_ty_static())::text, '',''::text)))' as s_t
)
select substring(s_t,POSITION('.' in s_t)+1) func from string;

o/p f_sel_policy_ty_static())::text, ','::text)))

But I want only f_sel_policy_ty_static

Comment: Unrelated note: consider upgrading your postgres! 9.4 is since Feb, 2020 no longer supported: https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql

Comment: Are you asking a question about this piece of SQL or about extracting a part of the query string? This is quite unclear and needs way more detail.

Comment: Yes, I'm want to extract  **f_sel_policy_ty_static** string from that large string using PostgreSQL

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. In this case provide table definition (ddl) and sample data for *f_sel_policy_ty_static* - as formatted text, **no images. Also, learn to format your query.